# if any value exists in any row than return it if not than return with null value

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
Col1 Col2
300   Null
300   A
300   B
400   NULL
```

I need output if any value exists in any row than return it if not than return with null value

Output:

```
Col1   Col2
300     A
300     B
400     Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a row if Col2 has a non-null value, or if same Col1 never has a non-null value for Col2.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where t1.Col2 is not null
   or not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.Col2 is not null
                    and t2.Col1 = t1.Col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 is not null
union all
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 is null and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.co2 is not null);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl(Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(100))INSERT INTO #Tbl(Col1 , Col2)
SELECT 300,Null UNION ALL SELECT 300,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 300,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 400,NULL 
SELECT Col1 , Col2
FROM #Tbl T1
WHERE ISNULL(Col2,'') <> ''
UNION ALL
SELECT Col1 , Col2
FROM #Tbl T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #Tbl T2 WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND ISNULL(T2.Col2,'') <> '')
```